# Error: Cannot find module cross-env using nodemon

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

I have installed nodemon in my app , when I run

`npm run prod`

I  get the following error

```
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\jelly\lavalite-new\cross-env'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

Here is package json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "nodemon cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "pug": "^2.0.3",
        "pug-loader": "^2.4.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "laravel-echo": "^1.4.0",
        "nodemon": "^1.18.4",
        "pusher-js": "^4.2.2",
        "urijs": "^1.19.1",
        "vue-content-loader": "^0.2.1",
        "vue-content-loading": "^1.5.3",
        "vue-filter": "^0.2.5",
        "vue-paginate": "^3.6.0",
        "vue2-autocomplete-js": "^0.2.2",
        "vuejs-auto-complete": "^0.7.0",
        "vuex": "^3.0.1",
        "vuex-i18n": "^1.10.5"
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is documentation](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#usage).

Your script `nodemon cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js` **is wrong**.

You pass to nodemon file `cross-env`. It [is a command](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) not a file. You should pass to `nodemon` your server file (file you whant to launch).

Correct script should be something like this:
`cross-env NODE_ENV=production nodemon node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js  --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`

Comment: I have installed npm install --save-dev cross-env
npm install but still the same

Comment: You have wrong script in your `package.json`.
It should be like this: `cross-env <ENV_VARIABLES> nodemon <FILE FOR NODEMON>`

Comment: Perfect solution but why my page is not reloading after changes?? what do I need to do to make it reload ? every changes I need to refresh the page the aim of installing nodemon I just wanted to make usre when i run `npm run prod` automatically it should reload the page

Comment: I believe you need `nodemon.json` config file. Have you checke [nodemon documentation](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#nodemon)?

Answer (score 0):

```
 "scripts": {
        "dev": "node node_modules/cross-env/src/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "node node_modules/cross-env/src/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "node node_modules/cross-env/src/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --watch-poll --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "hot": "node node_modules/cross-env/src/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "node node_modules/cross-env/src/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).